# SQL Server: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate the shopping_time field in a table. Does anyone know why I would be getting the error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

My table has customer_id, household_id, month, year, grocery_store, shopping_time.

```
select 
    u.customer_id, u.household_id, u.month, u.year, u.grocery_store, 
    SUM(u.shopping_time)
from 
    usage_counters_monthly u
group by
    (u.customer_id, u.household_id, u.month, u.year, u.grocery_store)
```

Comment: Jusr remove the brackets in the group by clause

Comment: thank you! solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parentheses in the `group by`:

```
select u.customer_id, u.household_id, u.month, u.year, u.grocery_store, SUM(u.shopping_time)
from usage_counters_monthly u
group by u.customer_id, u.household_id, u.month, u.year, u.grocery_store;
```

In many databases, this would be an error.  However, some databases support tuples.  In these databases, you have an inconsistency between the `select` and the `group by`, which would be causing your error.